# Passing props to component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was developing an React application, but had a confusion regarding passing of prop to the component.

On checking the internet, i found out that passing props is by adding it in route-

`<Route exact path='/'  render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} active={1} />}`

But an issue i encountered was,since all my routes were inside a switch statement at app.js, how to i pass the prop from a different page.

eg: This is my folder structure -

-App.js

-Movie Folder

---movie_page.js

---description_page.js

suppose that i had a `link` statement in the movie_page, to go to the description_page and i wanted to pass some calculated quantity to description_page as a prop, how do i achieve this?
All my routes are in App.js, and the value i want to pass as prop is calculated only in movie_page.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters through the `Link`.for example, you should have a route like this

```
<Route 
path="/description/:value1" 
render={props => <Description {...props} />}
/>
```

and in movie page

```
<Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/description/samplevalue",
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
        param3: { id: 1, name: "jack" }
      }}
    >
      Description
</Link>
```

Now you can access to all parameters:

```
  <div>
    Description page
    <h4> {this.props.match.params.value1}</h4>
    <h4> {this.props.location.param1}</h4>
    <h4> {this.props.location.param2}</h4>
    <code> {JSON.stringify(this.props.location.param3)}</code>
  </div>
```

Working Codesandbox [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-4-example-3kz3u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
, I hope it would be useful